# Are there any guides on integrating Action Block-like features to your Android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I'm currently trying to get my app to trigger Google Assistant commands à la Action Blocks and I was wondering what would be the best way to do so.

I usually prefer not to ask help with problems this non-specific, but I feel completely lost on the subject. Most of the material I've managed to find seem to focus on creating Assistant Actions that trigger app features instead of the other way around.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apps do not have ways to directly trigger an Assistant command. If you want to link directly to a third-party action, you can use [Assistant Links](https://developers.google.com/assistant/engagement/assistant-links) but you cannot programmatically call up something like the weather.